# How ta make a custom progress bar for media player on Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I'm developing a media player based on libvc, I want to make a progress bar like the one in Kmplayer for example, I'm thinking in a bar that shows the progress but also allow me to change the position of the movie with a click on the desired position on the bar. Also the Kmplayer's progress bar shows the title of the movie in the left side and the duration/elapsed time in the rigth side.(Attached Picture shows desired effects marked in green)

How can I copy that look? I think that I need to create my own subclass of QProgressBar but Could someone point me in the rigth direction please? …

Kmplayer Progress Bar Picture

[image]

Comment: To control the position with mouse, subclass the [mouse events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent). For the text informations, you can take a look to the [paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#paintEvent) function.

Comment: Thanks Thibaut B. I'm on it

Comment: You could tell me the time format you want to display.

Comment: eyllanesc : the time format will be like hh:mm:ss

Comment: @ThibautB. I worked with the mouse events and achieved what I want, but I need some help with the paintEvent(), I supose paintEvent() is in charge of update the progress bar text every time setValue() is executed, I don't have any experience subclassing paintEvent() and don't now how to reimplement drawText() for my own duration/elapsed time. I seeked out over the web but not find any example for overriding QPaintEvent and drawText on a QProgressBar. Can you help me please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example of [`paintEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#paintEvent):

```
void ProgressBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QProgressBar::paintEvent(e); // draw default
    // draw your information
    QPainter painter(this);

    // the pen
    QPen pen = painter.pen();
    pen.setColor(Qt::black);

    // write
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawText(1, 1, width()-1, height()-1,
        Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter,
        "filename.mp4");
    painter.drawText(1, 1, width()-1, height()-1,
        Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter,
        "your time");
    painter.end();
}
```

Will give you something like this:
[image: your own progress bar]

Comment: @ThibautB.Thanks a lot. This example is extactly what I need to understand QPaintEvent insides. I'll soon post the rest of my code for anyone that need something similar.

Comment: @silverhawk, If you don't want the percent of the progress bar, read this part of the doc: [```setTextVisible()```](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#textVisible-prop), if all is ok, don't forget to accept the answer.